# Error installing PyCurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I tried installing pycurl via pip. it didn't work and instead it gives me this error.

```
running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'pycurl' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv
-Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc
-arch x86_64 -pipe -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/
Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/pycurl.c -o
build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/pycurl.o

src/pycurl.c:85:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL
support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used;
thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause
random crashes on SSL requests"

/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/
../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/
ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed

Installed assemblers are:

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386

src/pycurl.c:85:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL
support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used;
thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause
random crashes on SSL requests"

src/pycurl.c:3906: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe

compilation terminated.

src/pycurl.c:85:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL
support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used;
thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause
random crashes on SSL requests"

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccspAJOg.out (No such file or
directory)

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What architecture, x86 or PowerPC?

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but have you considered urllib2 instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it working using this

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl
```

Comment: "sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install pycurl" worked for me. Thanks Mickey!

Answer (score 0):

if you are on linux with apt-get:

```
lnx#> apt-get search pycurl
```

To install:

```
lnx#> sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

if on linux with yum:

```
lnx#> yum search pycurl  
I get this on my comp:  
python-pycurl.x86_64 : A Python interface to libcurl
```

To install i've did:

`lnx#> sudo yum install python-pycurl`

Another alternative, is to use easy_install:

yum, or apt-get, install setuptools.

---

If you're using Holly Windows, then get pycurl from [HERE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl)